Is there any rule in Hebrew that requires pronouns to refer to an antecedent rather than a subsequent subject?
This question came about while studying and discussing Genesis 6:4. The Bible-hub Interlinear has both, “The Nephilim”, capitalized and, “Those”, capitalized:
“When the sons of God went into the daughters of men and they bore to them Those.”
It would seem that the translators  recognize something specific in the
grammar that caused them to capitalize “Those”, as a pronoun that refers to the antecedent name, “The Nephilim”, rather than referring to the subsequent noun “men of renown”.

I straightened out the terminology in my answer.

בַּיָּמִ֣ים הָהֵם֒ is "in those days" in Hebrew. הָהֵם֒ יָּמִ֣ים would be "those are the days..." Thus, הֵ֧מָּה הַגִּבֹּרִ֛ים is "Those were the mighty..." "Those" is capitalized because it starts a new sentence in English.  וְיָלְד֖וּ לָהֶ֑ם "They bore [children] to them..." might add to the confusion, but word order matters in Hebrew.

(c)      The predicative use of the demonstrative pronoun corresponds with the predicative use of the adjective; in other words, it can be placed before the noun and it agrees with it in gender and number.

 וְאֵ֛לֶּה תּוֹלְדֹ֥ת אַהֲרֹ֖ן
 And these are the generations of Aaron (Num. 3:1).*


Van der Merwe, C. H. J., Naudé, J. A., & Kroeze, J. H. (2017). A Biblical Hebrew Reference Grammar (Second Edition, p. 302). Bloomsbury; Bloomsbury T&T Clark: An Imprint of Bloomsbury Publishing Plc.

Note it is after the noun when modifying it.

(1)      The demonstrative pronoun can modify a noun.

 וְהֵֽבֵא֯יתִי֮ עַל־הָאָ֣רֶץ הַהִ֔יא
 And I will bring upon that land (Jer. 25:13).*


Ibid., p. 303.

